# How to use permutation test to create null distribution for categorical data?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, permutation-test

Consider a population of 1,000,000 individuals. I have examined them all and identified 1000 samples which I believe are not like others. To confirm this I analyzed the 1000 sample regarding one criteria which classified them in 4 groups. I want to show that the distribution of this sample is different from the rest of population so I randomly chose 1000 samples, analyzed them regarding that criteria and classified into 4 groups. chi square showed my group and randoms have different distribution in 4 groups.
However, the journal reviewer mentioned that simple chi square test using one random samples is not enough and null distribution should be created using permutations to confirm the results
I know how to use permutation test for confirming t-test however I could not find the proper way for chi square test. I appreciate if anybody could give me a hint.

Comment: If you actually have the entire *populations* about which you want to perform inference, there's nothing to do; either they are different or they aren't, no need for statistics (which is for making inferences about the population when you don't have the whole population).

Comment: Sorry I  think I described it wrong. One of the groups is total population  and other is a subset of big other population randomly chosen to see whether the first group is really different from the whole second population or not?

Comment: Sorry that's a little unclear. You have two populations, one of which you have all of and the other of which you have only a sample?

Comment: Also what was the reviewer's objection to the chi-square, exactly? What chi-square test did you do?

Comment: Lets explain it fully. Consider a population of 1,000,000 individuals. I have examined them all and identified 1000 samples which I believe are not like others. To confirm this I analyzed the 1000 sample regarding one criteria which classified them in 4 groups. I want to show that the distribution of this sample is different from the rest of population so I randomly chose 1000 samples, analyzed them regarding that criteria and classified into 4 groups. chi square showed my group and randoms have different distribution in 4 groups. How should I confirm this result?

Comment: reviewers comment :"...retrieving random sequences one time and comparing to your test conditions is not sufficient to reject the null. You should run permutations here to create a null distribution and compare. You can then calculate an empirical p-value over many permutations"

Comment: When you say you "identified 1000 samples" ... 1. What was the sample size of each of those samples (how many individuals)? 2. If you identified these by looking at the groups or the inputs to the critieria by which they were sorted into groups, you can't do hypothesis testing on those same values. 3. What you're actually trying to do there isn't clear - do you have two populations like you said before or not? This is really not clearly explained.